# What's a good module for moderating content submissions?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

Drupal 7.x. I'm looking for a module where it allows me to moderate any content submissions prior to them being published. For example:

I have writers, editors, and publishers groups. I want the writer to create the content, then the editors MUST look over the content to check for errors/mistypes, and THEN publishers take a last look and push the content to be published.

Is there a module that can handle this task for Drupal 7.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) will accomplish what you need. I am not sure of your exact workflow requirements.

Comment: I am not sure if this module is suitable (maybe I am wrong, but I can not found any feature of "Content Access" related for moderating content submissions)

Comment: Like @moon.watcher said I'm not sure if this is a good option.

Answer (score 5):

The [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module will help you. You could set up some [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to accomplish the same tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Another good option to accomplish this is using the [Workflow module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow).

Answer (score 0):

And also you can simply use views, and make something like dashboard for anyone of your groups and add it to their menu (limit the access for other roles)